# Undefined Method wday for Date Class

Tags: ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

```
2.0.0p247 :026 > Date.today.wday
 => 5 
2.0.0p247 :027 > Date.today.cwday
 => 5 
2.0.0p247 :028 >
```

This works perfectly in the console for the app an when I run the app on a local server I get:

```
undefined method `wday=' for Fri, 10 Jan 2014:Date
```

This is the code snippet in the app ( I also tried .cwday method with the same results):

```
<% if Time.now > Time.parse("10:30:00") && Time.now > Time.parse("00:00:00") && (Date.today.wday = 1 || Date.today.wday = 3 || Date.today.wday = 4) %>
```

Why does it work perfectly in the console (and in irb) but not when I run the app? Probably simple but I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's saying that `wday` doesn't have a setter - i.e. it's readonly. That's why it shows `wday=` undefined rather than `wday`.

For some reason it's treating your `Date.today.wday = 1` as an assignment, not an equality check, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that as in a couple in languages the comparison operator is `==`